# how to Add list of products from cart?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

dears,
i have an API working with ASP.Net Core 3.1 posting orders
i want to post order head and get all items from another api in cart items and post it in order items my code as below

```
[HttpPost("addOrderHead")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<OrderDto>> Posting(OrderDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dto == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var mappedEntities = _mapper.Map<Order>(dto);
            _orderRepository.Add(mappedEntities);
            if (await _orderRepository.Save())
            {
                
                int id = mappedEntities.OrderID;
                var cartItems = await _cartItemRepository.GetCartItems(mappedEntities.ApplicationUserId);

                var cartDto = new CartItemDto();
                foreach(var item in cartItems)
                {
                    cartDto.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                    cartDto.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode;
                    cartDto.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    cartDto.DepartmentID = item.DepartmentID;
                    cartDto.itemDescription = item.itemDescription;
                    cartDto.SubDescription3 = item.SubDescription3;
                    cartDto.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                    cartDto.Weight = item.Weight;
                    cartDto.SnapShotPrice = item.SnapShotPrice;
                    cartDto.StoreId = item.StoreId;
                    cartDto.barcode = item.barcode;
                    cartDto.Email = item.Email;
                    cartDto.ItemImage = item.ItemImage;
                };
                var items = new OrderItems()
                {
                    OrderId = id,
                    ItemID = cartDto.ItemID,
                    ItemLookupCode = cartDto.ItemLookupCode,
                    CategoryID = cartDto.CategoryID,
                    DepartmentID = cartDto.DepartmentID,
                    itemDescription = cartDto.itemDescription,
                    SubDescription3 = cartDto.SubDescription3,
                    Quantity = cartDto.Quantity,
                    Weight = cartDto.Weight,
                    SnapShotPrice = cartDto.SnapShotPrice,
                    StoreId = cartDto.StoreId,
                    barcode = cartDto.barcode,
                    Email = cartDto.Email,
                    ItemImage = cartDto.ItemImage,
                };
                _orderItemsRepository.Add(items);
                await _orderItemsRepository.Save();
                return Ok(id);
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
```

every time i run this api order header added successfully and order items add first item only
which cart items return with array of items ,
can any one help me in that ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `Add` (and maybe `.Save()`) inside the `foreach`:

```
var cartItems = await _cartItemRepository.GetCartItems(mappedEntities.ApplicationUserId);


foreach(var item in cartItems)
{
    var cartDto = new CartItemDto(); // inside foreach
    cartDto.ItemID = item.ItemID;
    ....

    var item = new OrderItems()  // one item - not: items
    {
        OrderId = id,
        ItemID = cartDto.ItemID,
        ...
        ItemImage = cartDto.ItemImage,
    };
    _orderItemsRepository.Add(item); // add item before moving to next item.
}
await _orderItemsRepository.Save();
```

BTW. I'm not sure why you need `cartDto`; I think you can eliminate it:

```
var cartItems = await _cartItemRepository.GetCartItems(mappedEntities.ApplicationUserId);


foreach(var item in cartItems)
{
    var item = new OrderItems()  // one item - not: items
    {
        OrderId = id,
        ItemID = item.ItemID,
        ...
        ItemImage = item.ItemImage,
    };
    _orderItemsRepository.Add(item); // add item before moving to next item.
}
await _orderItemsRepository.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct.In the below line you it should be List instead of object

```
var cartItems = await _cartItemRepository.GetCartItems(mappedEntities.ApplicationUserId);

                var cartDtoList = new List<CartItemDto>();
                foreach(var item in cartItems)
                {

                    carDto carDto= new CarDto();
                    cartDto.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                    cartDto.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode;
                    cartDto.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    cartDto.DepartmentID = item.DepartmentID;
                    cartDto.itemDescription = item.itemDescription;
                    cartDto.SubDescription3 = item.SubDescription3;
                    cartDto.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                    cartDto.Weight = item.Weight;
                    cartDto.SnapShotPrice = item.SnapShotPrice;
                    cartDto.StoreId = item.StoreId;
                    cartDto.barcode = item.barcode;
                    cartDto.Email = item.Email;
                    cartDto.ItemImage = item.ItemImage;
                    carDtoList.Add(carDto)
                };
```

**Similarly the orderItems will also be list**.

The other simplest solution is to put all the things inside foreach loop like this

```
foreach(var item in cartItems)
                {
                    cartDto.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                    cartDto.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode;
                    cartDto.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    cartDto.DepartmentID = item.DepartmentID;
                    cartDto.itemDescription = item.itemDescription;
                    cartDto.SubDescription3 = item.SubDescription3;
                    cartDto.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                    cartDto.Weight = item.Weight;
                    cartDto.SnapShotPrice = item.SnapShotPrice;
                    cartDto.StoreId = item.StoreId;
                    cartDto.barcode = item.barcode;
                    cartDto.Email = item.Email;
                    cartDto.ItemImage = item.ItemImage;
                
                var items = new OrderItems()
                {
                    OrderId = id,
                    ItemID = cartDto.ItemID,
                    ItemLookupCode = cartDto.ItemLookupCode,
                    CategoryID = cartDto.CategoryID,
                    DepartmentID = cartDto.DepartmentID,
                    itemDescription = cartDto.itemDescription,
                    SubDescription3 = cartDto.SubDescription3,
                    Quantity = cartDto.Quantity,
                    Weight = cartDto.Weight,
                    SnapShotPrice = cartDto.SnapShotPrice,
                    StoreId = cartDto.StoreId,
                    barcode = cartDto.barcode,
                    Email = cartDto.Email,
                    ItemImage = cartDto.ItemImage,
                };
                _orderItemsRepository.Add(items);
                await _orderItemsRepository.Save();
                return Ok(id);
}
```